# Javascript increment operation order of evaluation

Tags: javascript, increment, operator-precedence

I know the what the postfix/prefix increment/decrement operators do. And in javascript, this seems to be no different.

While I can guess the outcome of this line easily:

```
var foo = 10; console.log(foo, ++foo, foo, foo++, foo); 
// output: 10 11 11 11 12
```

as `++` operators appear within separate expressions.

It gets a bit complicated as these operators appears within the same expression:

```
var foo = 10; console.log(foo, ++foo + foo++, foo);
// output[1]: 10 22 12
// Nothing unexpected assuming LTR evaluation

var foo = 10; console.log(foo, foo++ + ++foo, foo);
// output[2]: 10 22 12
// What? Ordering is now different but we have the same output.
// Maybe value of foo is evaluated lazily...

var foo = 10; console.log(foo, foo + ++foo, foo);
// output[3]: 10 21 11
// What?! So first 'foo' is evaluated before the increment?
```

and my question is, how does Javascript (V8 in this case, as I tested these in Chrome) end up evaluating the addition expression in 2nd and 3rd example differently?

Why does `foo` end up evaluating differently than `foo++`. Isn't postfix `++` supposed to increment after the expression and just evaluate to `foo` within expression?

Comment: I believe the behavior you are describing shows that in javascript, addition is *left associative*.  This means that the left expression in `left_expression + right_expression` is evaluated first.  The increment operator is behaving in the way that you expect, I believe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just look at:

```
foo++ + ++foo
```

Mentally rewrite it to:

```
foo++ →
    addition_lhs = foo  // addition_lhs == 10
    foo += 1            // foo == 11
++foo →
    foo += 1            // foo == 12
    addition_rhs = foo  // addition_rhs == 12

addition_lhs + addition_rhs == 10 + 12 == 22
```

And `foo + ++foo`:

```
foo →
    addition_lhs = foo  // addition_lhs == 10
++foo →
    foo += 1            // foo == 11
    addition_rhs = foo  // addition_rhs == 11

addition_lhs + addition_rhs == 10 + 11 == 21
```

So everything is evaluated left to right, including the incrementation.

The crucial rule to understand is that in JavaScript the **whole** left hand side (LHS) is executed, and the value memorized, before any operation gets done on the right hand side (RHS).

You can either confirm the evaluation order by [reading the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-addition-operator-plus) or just place a runtime error in your expression and look what happens:

```
alert(1) + alert(2) + (function () { throw Error(); })() + alert(3)
```

Comment: So I just had to know the increment happens immediately after the sub-expression (after `a` then after `b` in `a + b`), not full expression (after `a + b`). 

Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Understand that when you use `foo++` you're telling to the "compiler": after you push it to the stack, increment it. When you use `++foo` you're telling the other way: increment it then push it to the stack.
The `++` operator have preference over the `+`, since the "compiler" read the expression this way `(foo++)+(++foo)`

Answer (score 1):

> var foo = 10; console.log(foo, ++foo + foo++, foo);

```
++foo + foo++
   11 + 11
```

The pre increment sets foo to 11 then adds it to foo again which is still 11, evaluating to 22 before foo is again incremented.

> var foo = 10; console.log(foo, foo++ + ++foo, foo);

```
foo++ + ++foo
10    +    12
```

By the time we reach ++foo, the value has already incriminated from foo++

> var foo = 10; console.log(foo, foo + ++foo, foo);

```
foo + ++foo
10  +   11
```

foo is incremented before we add it to foo, thus giving us 10 + 11

**SUMMARY**

Basically it all depends on what the current value of foo is when you add them together.