# JavaScript strange behavior with operator precedence!!!1

Tags: javascript, operators, operator-precedence

What do you think will be result of this expression?

```js
var a = 10;
a = a + (a = 5);
console.log(a);

// a = 10?
```

NO!!! It's 15!

Now lets look at the other similar statement:

```js
var a = 10;
    a = (a = 5) + a;
    console.log(a);
    
    // a = 15?
```

Again no, now its 10. Why is that? I cant understand. But wait, there is two more:

```js
var a = 10;
a = a + a++;
console.log(a);

// a = 21? Haha no! Its 20!
```

And the last one:

```js
var a = 10;
a = a++ + a;
console.log(a);

// 21))) now my mind is blown away (
```

So can anybody tell, why javascript behaves this way?

Comment: I just wonder why they are correct, i dont say they aren't

Comment: what about first two examples?

Comment: While all the questions you have are grounded in the same *basic* issue (**What order are operations carried out in when I assign a value to the same variable multiple times in the same expression?** — which is a terrible idea in the first place ), I'm voting to close this as too broad because they are separate problems (and there are probably separate duplicates for each issue floating around anyway).

Comment: Do you think i havent tried to find the answer? If thats so simple why you dont just give a link to a similar problem that have been discussed. thx

Comment: The first two seem pretty straight-forward to me: `var a = 10; a = a + (a = 5);` is the same as `a = 10 + 5;`. At the moment the first `a` is evaluated, it has the value `10`. `(a = 5)` evaluates to `5` (the result of the assignment expression). The fact that you assigned the value to `a` is irrelevant since are not reading from it anymore. However, in `a = (a = 5) + a;`, you first assign to `a`, so when you read from it (`... + a`) it has the value `5`. It's the same a `a = 5 + 5`.

Comment: *"If thats so simple why you dont just give a link to a similar problem that have been discussed."* Everything can be answered by reading the spec ;) Not that that is easy though... https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/

Comment: More accessible references: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34094916/218196, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50869790/218196

Comment: but it completly negates everything that is taught about operator precedence... The expresion in parentheses must evaluate first? Than goes addition..

Comment: *"The expresion in parentheses must evaluate first?"* That's not what parenthesis mean. I guess one could say that they impact the order of evaluation (but that does not necessarily mean that they are evaluated first, just imagine you have multiple groups of parenthesis, they cannot be "first" all together). Rather they change the precedence  of operands/operators and operators, which as a side effect impacts evaluation order. E.g. `3 * 4 + 5` is different than `3 * (4 + 5)`. The LHS of `x * y`, i.e. `3` is still evaluated first. The difference is in evaluating the RHS, `4` vs `4 + 5`.

Comment: After this comment i come with an idea to write a new bestseller 'You dont know JS operators'

Comment: The examples with `a++` are also pretty straight-forward. It does what it should: return the current value of `a`, *then* increase it by one.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this better, let us consider another variable

**CASE 1**

```js
var a = 10;
a = a + (a = 5); 
console.log(a); // 15

a = 10;
var b = a + (a = 5);
console.log(a); // 5
console.log(b); // 15
```

```
a + (a = 5)
5 + (a = 5) // here a is assigned a value 5 and bracket returns 5
5 + 5 // here value of a is 5
10 // value will be assigned to variable on LHS
```

**CASE 2**

```js
var a = 10;
a = (a = 5) + a;
console.log(a); // 10


a = 10;
var b = (a = 5) + a;
console.log(a); // 5
console.log(b); // 10
```

```
(a = 5) + a
(a = 5) + a // here a is assigned a value 5 and bracket returns value 5
5 + 5 // here value of a is 5
10 // value will be assigned to variable on LHS
```

**CASE 3**

```js
var a = 10;
a = a + a++;
console.log(a); // 20

a = 10;
var b = a + a++;
console.log(a); // 11
console.log(b); // 20
```

```
a + a++ // post increment i.e. it will return the value first and then increment
10 + 10 // where value of a will 10 + 1 i.e. 11 
20 // value will be assigned to variable on LHS
```

**CASE 4**

```js
var a = 10;
a = a++ + a;
console.log(a); // 21

a = 10;
var b = a++ + a;
console.log(a); // 11
console.log(b); // 21
```

```
a++ + a // post increment i.e. it will return the value first and then increment
10 + a // where value of a will 10 + 1 i.e. 11
10 + 11 // as value of a is 11
21 // value will be assigned to variable on LHS
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = 10;
a = a + (a = 5);
console.log(a);

// a = 10?
```

It's 15 because the value of **a** was 10 and you added **(a = 5)** after, which changed **a**'s value to 5. Therefore, you did 10+5.

```js
var a = 10;
    a = (a = 5) + a;
    console.log(a);
    
    // a = 15?
```

Now that you have **(a = 5)** first, you're changing its value to 5 **before** adding **a**. Therefore, you're doing 5+5.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the expression in parentheses must be evaluated first, i thought that what operator precedence mean